# In Symfony-Sonata all fields are sortable except for one

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

In [Sonata](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/) I have created several lists and all work fine. (Please not that that was a while ago, so I may have done something there which fixed the issue I will describe here...).

Now I have created a new listing of Playlist entities:
[image]

As you can see in the picture, both the "Id" column and the "Aangemaakt op" columns are sortable, however the "Playlist" column is not.

Both the "Aangemaakt op" and the "Playlist" fields are **date-fields**, but since the "Aangemaakt op" field is sortable I would say that has nothing to do with it.

I have been searching the Sonata documentation, Google and StackOverflow, but haven't found any clue concerning this issue. I did find thread about sorting a list based on an Entity field, but my field isn't an entity.

Relevant code:

```
/**
 * @param ListMapper $listMapper
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
    $listMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('playlist_date', 'date', array('label' => 'Playlist'))
        ->add('created', 'datetime', array('label' => 'Aangemaakt op'))
        ->add(
            '_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'delete' => array(),
                )
            )
        );
}
```

Some StackOverflow threads and an answer below mention adding `'sortable' => true` to the field that must be sortable.

Doing that indeed makes the column clickable to sort, but clicking it results in the following exception:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery::entityJoin() 
must be of the type array, null given, called in
/path/of/my/project/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Datagrid/ProxyQuery.php
on line 142 and defined.
```

According to other StackOverflow threads that is because a join must be created. However, the field is simply a field of the same Mysql record as the other fields. I did find a StackOverflow thread mentioning this as well and in which they joined the same record in order to make this work, but I didn't get that to work. Besides, I thank that shouldn't be the way to order the contents of a column.

Does anyone have a clue?

**Update in reaction to Hibatallah Aouadni's answer**

As Hibatallah suggests, I added the following to my PlaylistsAdmin:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('playlist_date')
        ->add('created');
}
```

This resulted in the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: playlist_date
```

So I inspected my Entity and I found that it has a UniqueConstraint:

```
uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="playlist_date", columns={"playlist_date"})}
```

It does not have an actual "index" defined, but ofcourse it is. However as a test I added the following:

```
, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="playlist_date", columns={"playlist_date"})}
```

This didn't give any different result.
So still no luck at all :(

** Entity and Entity admin **

Entity Admin:

```
<?php

namespace Company\AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class PlaylistsAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'playlists';
    protected $baseRouteName = 'playlists';

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        $collection->clearExcept(array('list', 'delete', 'show'));
    }

    /**
     * @param ListMapper $listMapper
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
        $listMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('playlist_date', 'date', array('label' => 'Playlist'))
            ->add('created', 'datetime', array('label' => 'Aangemaakt op'))
            ->add(
                '_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'show' => array(),
                    /*'edit' => array(),*/
                    'delete' => array(),
                )
            )
            );
    }

    public function getBatchActions() {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Company\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Playlist
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="playlist", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="playlist_date", columns={"playlist_date"})})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Playlist
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="playlist_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $playlistDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    protected $video;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->video = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set playlistDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $playlistDate
     * @return Playlist
     */
    public function setPlaylistDate($playlistDate) {
        $this->playlistDate = $playlistDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playlistDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPlaylistDate() {
        return $this->playlistDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Playlist
     */
    public function setCreated($created) {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Add video
     *
     * @param \Company\AppBundle\Entity\Video $video
     * @return Playlist
     */
    public function addVideo(\Company\AppBundle\Entity\Video $video) {
        $this->video[] = $video;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove video
     *
     * @param \Company\AppBundle\Entity\Video $video
     */
    public function removeVideo(\Company\AppBundle\Entity\Video $video) {
        $this->video->removeElement($video);
    }

    /**
     * Get video
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getVideo() {
        return $this->video;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried ->add('playlist_date', 'date', array('sortable' => true)) ?

Comment: Yes I did. I updated my question mentioning this solution and the Exception that will be thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found it, it's so absurd, in the configureListFields method, you have to call the attribute with its name not the DataBase name, so:

change

```
->add('playlist_date', 'date', array('label' => 'Playlist'))
```

to

```
->add('playlistDate', 'date', array('label' => 'Playlist'))
```

:D I can't beleive we spend all this time for some absurd mistake ;)

Comment: LOL thanks for diving into it. That was it!! Indeed really absurd we didn't see that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to add the argument sortable to array and true as value:

```
->add('playlist_date', 'date', array(
   'label' => 'Playlist',
   'sortable' => true
))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't work (yet). I updated my question, mentioning the fact that an Exception will be thrown when applying your solution.

Comment: @vrijdenker can you please try to change 'date' to null and make me updated

Comment: That results in "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

Comment: @vrijdenker can you change it to 'datetime'? what gives you?

Comment: The output of the field adds "00:00:00", but the field is still not sortable.

Comment: @vrijdenker sorry I really wanna help you but it seems I can't figure out the problem

Comment: Yes thanks a lot for your help anyway :) I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the playlist field in configureDatagridFilters in your entity admin:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('playlist_date')
        ->add('created');
}
```

and it will work ;)

Comment: Thank you for your insights. However, I had no luck with it. I updated my post explaining what I did.

Comment: @vrijdenker can you please show me your entity (the class) and if it's ok for you the entityAdmin, we may find something

Comment: Sure! I just added them to the post.